# SQL Query to fetch the name who are getting more than the average salary of employees working in IT and OPERATION

Tags: sql

```
Name    Salary  Department
A   9568    IT
B   7854    IT
C   8564    IT
D   4875    IT
E   5895    HR
F   8858    HR
G   9858    HR
H   11852   FINANCE
I   7582    OPERATION
J   5892    OPERATION
K   12850   FINANCE
L   5265    STORE
M   3582    STORE
N   8520    FINANCE
```

Write a SQL query to fetch the names whose salary is greater than average salary of people working in  department IT and OPERATION

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Btw: there is no employee that works in IT **and** OPERATION in your sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @value = AVERAGE(Salary) FROM YOURTABLE WHERE department in ('OPERATION', 'IT')
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE Salary > @value;
```

I think that should work. Replace YOURTABLE with your table's name.

Comment: That is not SQL, that's T-SQL